# Fetching a value of a text box in a matrix report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working with a matrix report in ssrs. 
Here is a sample screenshot of my report extracted in excel 
[image]

The report is simple enough. It shows the data for different years **(example : AS OF JAN,2012).**
The netrevenue for the years are defined in the database so they are fetched accordingly. The problem is with the other sub columns. Like the **"%Change"** column.

The column value is calculated with the help of following formula

```
%change = ((NetRevenue of The current year / NetRevenue of the last year) - 1) * 100
```

Now what I doing to solve this problem is calculate the values using sql queries for every column and then binding it directly to the control.

My question is that is there a simpler way to do this. I mean like in table control I can access the value of a cell by using

```
  ReportItems!Textbox1.Value
```

Is there a way I can access the dynamic columns of the matrix report. Like accessing the netRevenue values for different years.

If more clarification is needed for the question then please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to us the `inscope` function, http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/ssrs-problem-subtotal-calculating-147541.aspx

Comment: Wow try this for a detailed understanding. You'll need to tweak it for you report. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0bde66d7-b0e4-40da-9a0c-838663e66119 ..... I'll go now...@askitsuhail

Comment: thanks for your interest in this question. Let me study it and I will soon post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only issue your going to have is getting the revenue at the past year?

In this case you'll need to calculate the last years revenue in the sql. Then use:

```
=((RpItems!NetRev.Value / RpItems!NetRev_LastYr.Value) - 1) * 100
```

With this case you'll need to calculate all the last years values for the % changes you want to calculate.

Can I suggest you look into this and raise another question with the sql you currently have?

I've found this works best.

Comment: thanks for the answer but what if I have multiple years? Like from 2009 to 2012 and every net revenue %change needs to be calculated from its previous year. I am doing it successfully by calculating the values at the back-end using sql queries. I believe that the ReportItems!item.Value do not work with a matrix field. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks again for an answer.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by matrix field. But what you have done already seems the best, although a possible optimisation exists using a single sql.

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd255256(v=sql.105).aspx) out. There must be some hidden dealings with the aggregate function and the data scope.

Comment: By matrix field I mean the textbox field of a matrix. Like in a table control.

Comment: I'm in over my head as I've delt with matrix reports in detail but the way i made a similar method work seem to be the same as you.

Comment: It seems as though if you have used the same field for all the years, as you should, you can't. :( But I've had limited research. Good luck and I'm now quite interested your result.